# getting Status from Twitter using twitter4j on Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to retrieve status with Twitter4j, but I get a Unfortunately TestProject has stopped error and my app closes. I am also not getting anything in logcat so I do not know where to start troubleshooting.

This is the method executed when a button is pressed, I am basically making an instance of the class which contains all the oAuth setup and the call to the twitter API for the status. I know this should probably be done with an Async call since it deals with network, but for now I just wanted to retrieve a status even if the UI is blocked:

```
    public void onGetStatus(View v){

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){



        GetUserStatus status = new GetUserStatus();
        ResponseList<Status> a = status.twitterSettings();

        for(Status s: a){
        editText.setText(s.getText());

        }

    }

}
```

This is the class with all the twitter configurations for my account.

```
public class GetUserStatus {



public ResponseList<Status> twitterSettings(){

  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
  cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxx");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxx");



TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();


try {
    ResponseList<Status> a = twitter.getUserTimeline(new Paging(1,5));

    return  a;


} catch (TwitterException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();


}
return null;





}
```

}

**Research I have done**

I have been mostly going off twitter4j's website [code examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) and it seems everything is up to date so I dont think twitter4j is deprecated. I have also looked through other twitter4j questions on StackOverflow.com but most deal with 404 error or some other type of error, while I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Did you check whether the user is still exist and accessible from twitter.com UI? The user account might be suspended or deleted or protected somehow. Make sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was StrictMode.ThreadPolicy was introduced since API Level 9 and the default thread policy had been changed since API Level 11, which in short, does not allow network operation

(eg: HttpClient and HttpUrlConnection) get executed on UI thread. If you do this, you get NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Using AsyncTask fixed the issue. I added a nested class within my activity

```
class GetUserStatus extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, ResponseList < twitter4j.Status >> {

        @
        Override
        protected ResponseList < twitter4j.Status > doInBackground(Void...params) {


            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
            cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXX");
            cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXX");
            cb.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXX");
            cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXX");




            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();



            try {
                ResponseList < twitter4j.Status > a = twitter.getUserTimeline(new Paging(1, 5));


                return a;

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseList < twitter4j.Status > stats) {

            for (twitter4j.Status a: stats) {

                editText.setText(a.getText());



            }

        }




    }
```

The other issue I was having with logcat not displaying exceptions, was because Eclipse automatically selected a filter, when I chose the option "all messages (no filter)" I was able to see the stack  trace.

[image: logcat filter]